# ColdFusion - String Remove Characters after certain spot

Tags: string, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

String length is always formatted like this - but varies in length.

*Add: BLLAHHH Blahhh Blahhhhh Blahhh Det: HSD03 Evt: F2014999999 NOTICE - This communication is intended ONLY for the use of the person or entity named above and may contain information that is confidential or legally privileged. Blahhh Blahhh Blahhh*

I am trying to get only the data ending at end of number

*Add: BLLAHHH Blahhh Blahhhhh Blahhh Det: HSD03 Evt: F2014999999*

I have tried a variety of string functions with not much luck.

Code below gets me to:

*Add: BLLAHHH Blahhh Blahhhhh Blahhh Det: HSD03 Evt: F2014999999 NOTICE*

```
     <cfset string = "#textbody#">
     <br>
     <cfset firstPiece = listGetAt(string, 1, "-")>
     [ [ <cfoutput>#firstPiece#</cfoutput> ] ]
```

Comment: From where you are, you can treat firstPiece as as space delimited list and delete the last item.  A better approach would be to use a regular expression but you need someone smarter than me to show you how.

Comment: Can you confirm that the string always has "Add: [stuff] Det: [stuff] Evt: [stuff] [SPACE]? IE: the `Add:`, `Det:`, `Evt:` and `[SPACE]` are guaranteed, irrespective of the values between them?

Comment: is what you want always going to be right before `"NOTICE -"`?

Comment: Correct - Add: Stuff Det: Stuff Evt: Stuff and always before "NOTICE -" - I am doing a <cfset final = left(fp, len(fp) -9)> - which then strips the final and works off the - delimiter.  But doesn't work if there is another "-" in the mix somewhere.  Is there a way to work off the "NOTICE -"

Comment: Basically if I could strip out everything after notice - I could then just strip the last 6 characters to get wht I need.  Code below kinda works - but errored - The 2 parameter of the Left function, which is now 0, must be a positive integer

Answer (score 3):

```
function trimToLastEndWithDigit(str) {
    var noticePos = find(" NOTICE -", str);
    return left(str, noticePos);
}

str = "Add: BLLAHHH Blahhh Blahhhhh Blahhh Det: HSD03 Evt: F2014999999 NOTICE - This communication is intended ONLY for the use of the person or entity named above and may contain information that is confidential or legally privileged. Blahhh Blahhh Blahhh";

writeOutput(trimToLastEndWithDigit(str));
```

http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=c9N8NEUD

I was trying to use regex to satisfy your need before, but what you need is actually much simpler, so please ignore the function name.

Comment: if there is no notice text, function left will be fail

Comment: so add if(noticePos == 0) return str;

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex as follows:
Your String:

```
<cfset testString = "Add: BLLAHHH Blahhh Blahhhhh Blahhh Det: HSD03 Evt: F2014999999 NOTICE - This communication is intended ONLY for the use of the person or entity named above and may contain information that is confidential or legally privileged. Blahhh Blahhh Blahhh"/>
```

Regex:

```
<cfset testSt = ReReplace(testString,"NOTICE.*","")>
```

Output:

```
Add: BLLAHHH Blahhh Blahhhhh Blahhh Det: HSD03 Evt: F2014999999
```

Comment: This will work fine unless there is a string - "NOTICE" after any of the strings- Add:, Det:, Evt:. 
For eg. if the string is "Add: NOTICE Blahhh Blahhhhh Blahhh Det: HSD03 Evt: F2014999999 NOTICE - This communication is intended ONLY for the use of the person or entity named above and may contain information that is confidential or legally privileged. Blahhh Blahhh Blahhh"
then the output will not be as desired.

Comment: @Tushar - Pankaj is right, but if you use the following regex, it uses a negative lookahead to make sure that it's picking the last NOTICE. `ReReplaceNoCase(RString,"(NOTICE)(?!.*NOTICE).*","ALL")`. The `NoCase` bit isn't even necessary if the OP can guarantee NOTICE is always in that case (which it very likely is, since it's probably a signature).

Answer (score 0):

Got it I think...

TextBody is:

Add: BLLAHHH Blahhh Blahhhhh Blahhh Det: HSD03 Evt: F2014999999 NOTICE - This communication is intended ONLY for the use of the person or entity named above and may contain information that is confidential or legally privileged. Blahhh Blahhh Blahhh

```
    <cfset fp = "#textbody#" />

    <cfoutput>#REReplace(fp, "NOTICE(.*)", "NOTICE")#</cfoutput>
    <cfset newstr = "#REReplace(fp, "NOTICE(.*)", "NOTICE")#">

    <cfset final = left(newstr, len(newstr) -7)>

     [<b>#final#</b>]
```